# Jenkins job url getting build incorrect for JenkinsJobTriggerOperator with Airflow

Tags: jenkins, airflow, jenkins-groovy, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to monitor a Jenkins job using Airflow. I followed the instructions mentioned below for:

a.  JenkinsJobTriggerOperator

b.  Configuring connection in Airflow UI

I am successfully able to make connection from Airflow to Jenkins but not able to submit job and getting error:
“requests.exceptionsHTTPError: 404 Client Error:Not Found for url: https://example.com:443/job/Project/job/job/job/TestPipeline/job/job/job/dev/build

After observing closely, I noticed the build url which is getting created by host + port + Jenkins job is incorrect in a particular pattern. "job" keyword is present 3 times, instead of 1 time.

The above incorrect build url looks like:  https://example.com:443/job/Project/job/job/job/TestPipeline/job/job/job/dev/build

The expected one should be: https://example.com:443/job/Project/job/TestPipeline/job/dev/build

Airflow code snipped:

```
with dag:

    trigger_jenkins_job = JenkinsJobTriggerOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id='trigger_jenkins_job',
        job_name='Project/job/TestPipeline/dev',
        jenkins_connection_id="Jenkins_test")
```

Comment: Can you share code snippets of how the `JenkinsJobTriggerOperator` task is called in your DAG? Any other relevant code would be helpful as well.

Comment: @josh Fell: I have added the Airflow code snippet

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the Jenkins API builds the folder path of the URL by adding `/job/` to the `job_name` supplied by first splitting the `job_name` by "/" into list and then adding `/job/` to each element in that list. See [here](https://opendev.org/jjb/python-jenkins/src/branch/master/jenkins/__init__.py#L1738).

I was able to get the desired URL by using a `job_name` of "Project/TestPipeline/dev". You do not need to insert `/job/` throughout your `job_name` value.

Comment: Thanks Josh, it worked perfectly fine after removing "/job/" keyword from the path :-)

Comment: Excellent, that's great to hear! When you get a chance, would you kindly accept the answer for other users?